# How to make an Icon List Carousel on Elementor

Tags: wordpress, carousel, elementor

I need to create an icon list carousel like the image below:

[image: Example]

I need to make a session similar to this example, where it contains an icon, title, and subtitle in a carousel format. I tried some plugins but didn't find an solution.

Thanks.